# Classifying sequences of different lengths

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network

Despite going through [multiple](https://gist.github.com/Seanny123/0419e916f7f50cd77811c2b556d5ddeb) [examples](https://gist.github.com/Seanny123/1d63e493686dac41f4bcfe8f9f0aae81), I still don't understand how to classify sequences of varying length using Keras, [similar to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39660863/1079075). I can train a network that detects frequencies of sinusoid with varying length, by using masking:

```
from keras import models
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dense, Masking
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop
from keras.losses import categorical_crossentropy
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

import numpy as np


def gen_noise(noise_len, mag):
    return np.random.uniform(size=noise_len) * mag


def gen_sin(t_val, freq):
    return 2 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * t_val * freq)


def train_rnn(x_train, y_train, max_len, mask, number_of_categories):
    epochs = 3
    batch_size = 500

    # three hidden layers of 256 each
    vec_dims = 1
    hidden_units = 256
    in_shape = (max_len, vec_dims)

    model = models.Sequential()

    model.add(Masking(mask, name="in_layer", input_shape=in_shape,))
    model.add(LSTM(hidden_units, return_sequences=False))
    model.add(Dense(number_of_categories, input_shape=(number_of_categories,),
              activation='softmax', name='output'))

    model.compile(loss=categorical_crossentropy, optimizer=RMSprop())

    model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs,
              validation_split=0.05)

    return model


def gen_sig_cls_pair(freqs, t_stops, num_examples, noise_magnitude):
    x = []
    y = []

    num_cat = len(freqs)

    dt = 0.01
    max_t = int(np.max(t_stops) / dt)

    for f_i, f in enumerate(freqs):
        for t_stop in t_stops:
            t_range = np.arange(0, t_stop, dt)
            t_len = t_range.size

            for _ in range(num_examples):
                sig = gen_sin(f, t_range) + gen_noise(t_len, noise_magnitude)
                x.append(sig)

                one_hot = np.zeros(num_cat, dtype=np.bool)
                one_hot[f_i] = 1
                y.append(one_hot)

    pad_kwargs = dict(padding='post', maxlen=max_t, value=np.NaN, dtype=np.float32)
    return pad_sequences(x, **pad_kwargs), np.array(y)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    noise_mag = 0.01
    mask_val = -10
    frequencies = (5, 7, 10)
    signal_lengths = (0.8, 0.9, 1)

    x_in, y_in = gen_sig_cls_pair(frequencies, signal_lengths, 50, noise_mag)
    mod = train_rnn(x_in[:, :, None], y_in, 100, mask_val, len(frequencies))
```

However, I don't understand how I'm supposed to tell Keras about the other sequences. I thought I could mask them too, but when I try, they just output `NaN`.

```
testing_dat, expected = gen_sig_cls_pair(frequencies, signal_lengths, 1, 0)
res = mod.predict(testing_dat[:, :, None])

fig, axes = plt.subplots(3)
axes[0].plot(np.concatenate(testing_dat), label="input")

axes[1].plot(np.argmax(res, axis=1), "ro", label="result", alpha=0.2)
axes[1].plot(np.argmax(expected, axis=1), "bo", label="expected", alpha=0.2)
axes[1].legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.1, 1))

axes[2].plot(res)

plt.show()
```

How do I make a network that can evaluate inputs of varying lengths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [pad](https://keras.io/preprocessing/sequence/) the input sequences (usually with zeros) **or** you can use batches of size 1 with varying input size, as outlined in fchollet's [answer](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/85) on the Keras github:

```
for seq, label in zip(sequences, y):
    model.train(np.array([seq]), [label])
```

Alternatively, if your type of problem allows it, you extract subsequences of the original time series with length less than the length of the shortest sequences. The third option also allows you to add redundancy to the dataset if you have few samples, and reduce the chances of overfitting.

EDIT:

Seanny123 (OP) pointed out that fchollet's lines above contain `model.train`, which is not valid code. 
He solved the problem using batches of size 1 and the following code:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense
import numpy as np


def gen_sig(num_samples, seq_len):
    one_indices = np.random.choice(a=num_samples, size=num_samples // 2, replace=False)

    x_val = np.zeros((num_samples, seq_len), dtype=np.bool)
    x_val[one_indices, 0] = 1

    y_val = np.zeros(num_samples, dtype=np.bool)
    y_val[one_indices] = 1

    return x_val, y_val


N_train = 100
N_test = 10
recall_len = 20

X_train, y_train = gen_sig(N_train, recall_len)

X_test, y_test = gen_sig(N_train, recall_len)

print('Build STATEFUL model...')
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(10, batch_input_shape=(1, 1, 1), return_sequences=False, stateful=True))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

print('Train...')
for epoch in range(15):
    mean_tr_acc = []
    mean_tr_loss = []

    for seq_idx in range(X_train.shape[0]):
        start_val = X_train[seq_idx, 0]
        assert y_train[seq_idx] == start_val
        assert tuple(np.nonzero(X_train[seq_idx, :]))[0].shape[0] == start_val

        y_in = np.array([y_train[seq_idx]], dtype=np.bool)

        for j in range(np.random.choice(a=np.arange(5, recall_len+1))):
            x_in = np.array([[[X_train[seq_idx][j]]]])
            tr_loss, tr_acc = model.train_on_batch(x_in, y_in)

            mean_tr_acc.append(tr_acc)
            mean_tr_loss.append(tr_loss)

        model.reset_states()

    print('accuracy training = {}'.format(np.mean(mean_tr_acc)))
    print('loss training = {}'.format(np.mean(mean_tr_loss)))
    print('___________________________________')

    mean_te_acc = []
    mean_te_loss = []
    for seq_idx in range(X_test.shape[0]):
        start_val = X_test[seq_idx, 0]
        assert y_test[seq_idx] == start_val
        assert tuple(np.nonzero(X_test[seq_idx, :]))[0].shape[0] == start_val

        y_in = np.array([y_test[seq_idx]], dtype=np.bool)

        for j in range(np.random.choice(a=np.arange(5, recall_len+1))):
            te_loss, te_acc = model.test_on_batch(np.array([[[X_test[seq_idx][j]]]], dtype=np.bool), y_in)
            mean_te_acc.append(te_acc)
            mean_te_loss.append(te_loss)
        model.reset_states()

    print('accuracy testing = {}'.format(np.mean(mean_te_acc)))
    print('loss testing = {}'.format(np.mean(mean_te_loss)))
print('___________________________________')
```

Comment: Padding the input sequence isn't working for me, as I demonstrate in the question. However, I will try tomorrow to use the batch size of 1 trick. A link to a demonstration of this trick would be appreciated.

Comment: Added the code in my answer!

Comment: Your are right, I copypasted it from fchollet's answer (the creator of Keras) and I just assumed it would be correct. I'll edit my answer with your solution, looks great!