# Keras LSTM with varying timesteps

Tags: keras

Suppose the input to the model is a series of vectors, each with equal length. However, the number of vectors in each input can change. I want to make an LSTM model using Keras, but if I were to write

```
input = keras.layers.input(dims)
img_out = keras.layers.recurrent.LSTM(16)
```

Then what would I put for "dims"? Thanks so much.

Comment: I asked literally the same question yesterday https://stackoverflow.com/q/44241607/1079075

Answer (score 0):

You can fix an upper bound for `dims`. When the input is less than `dims`, you can pad the rest with zero vector.